# What is the use of "-u" option in JBOSS AS7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

In some [jboss related documentations](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/GTNPORTAL36/Clustering+configuration) found that they used -u option for starting the JBOSS AS7 server like follows.

```
$ ./bin/standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=node1 -b 192.168.210.101 -u 239.23.42.2 -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.210.101
```

What is the use of "-u" in JBOSS AS7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to set a multicast address, generally useful for high availability cluster configuration.

See [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters#Commandlineparameters-defaultmulticastaddress).